# Looking for a WordPress Quoting Plugin (Not WooCommerce)

Tags: wordpress, plug-in

I am looking for a wordpress plugin that can display the following columns in a table:
Book Image 
Book Author 
Book Title 
Book Description 
Price 
Quantity - User adjustable (drop down or plus/minus)

There would be around 60 rows, so data would either need to be uploaded from a csv, or taken from a post type.

The table would need to be able to be submitted, and I receive an email with the Title and quantity

The site already has a Woocommerce shop, this page is a separate quote system for wholesalers where the results are entered into a completely different system separate to the website. No payment is taken.

Is there a preferably free or not too expensive plugin that can do this? I have searched but just can't seem to find one.

Thanks in advance 
Jonathan